# maven - generate sources is not working

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

please advise if possible on this
I am running `mvn package source:jar` and get a module.jar and module-sources.jar as expected in the target directory
However, I have 2 issues:
1) I when I do : `mvn install source:jar` I get a -source.jar in my "target" in 
    the local projects folder, HOWEVER, NOT in the "local-repository (under .m2 
    on my PC).  Even though, I do get a module.jar with binaries installed.

EDIT:   I have figured this item (1):  It works if I place "source:jar" before "install".  That is `mvn source:jar install` instead of `mvn install source:jar`

2) I want to NOT HAVE TO run source:jar in the command line to generate the sources. Because, when I use GO continuous integration tool, that I have no control over, they do not have a maven goal `mvn source:jar` there.
 I know that with the configurations in the pom.xml it can be achieved, and I did see it occuring once or twice, but it stopped working (well, obviously I made a change,that I do not know that broke this)
My pom.xml has the following

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${source.directory}</outputDirectory>
            <finalName>${project.jar.name}</finalName>
            <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
            <classifier>${source.classifier}</classifier> 
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

So, ultimately, when I run either `mvn package` or `mvn install` or I want to have sources generated as a jar file next to the regular project.jar (or in the specified folder, but it is not essential)

Comment: First remove configuration for `outputDirectory`, `finalName`, `fileNameMapping` and `classifier`...afterwards make a simple `mvn clean package` and you should find the `xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ` in your `target` directory. If you do `mvn install` it will be installed in your local cache as well...BTW: Change the `goal` from `jar` to `jar-no-fork`...

Comment: :(  Did that too.  It still does not work ...  No -source jars are created .. :(

Comment: Make a test project on github...